# Netbeans opens http instead of https when running EAR

Tags: netbeans, https, glassfish, ear

I have a Maven Enterprise Application Project on which I'm working in my spare time. Currently, I want to switch over to HTTPS, but all I get is headaches.

So: I'm using NetBeans 8.1 with GlassFish 4.1.1 on Windows 10 Pro x64. Cleaning, building and running the application results in opening `http://localhost:8181/MyApp` instead of HTTPS within Firefox.
I already disabled the unsecured HTTP-listener in the GF admin console (loading URL with port 8181 indicates it works), but other than that. what's the cuplrit? Did I forget something?

EDIT: This seems to be a GlassFish 4.1.1 problem (tested quickly on Windows 7 x64 with Netbeans 8.0.2 and GF 4.1; also NetBeans 8.1 and GF 4.1). It seems the HTTPS-listeners cannot be started in time (marked with **! ! !**). Are there any known solutions or workarounds?

EDIT2: Re-enabling the unsecured HTTP-listener "fixes" the problem (loading `http://localhost:8080/MyApp` and redirecting to `http**s**://localhost:8181/MyApp`).

This is the server log upon running the EAR from within NetBeans:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Sep 21, 2016 3:56:05 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFORMATION: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Sep 21, 2016 3:56:05 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Sep 21, 2016 3:56:05 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Sep 21, 2016 3:56:06 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNUNG: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@3f6b4900 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Information:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Information:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Information:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Information:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Information:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Information:   Network listener http-listener-1 on port 8080 disabled per domain.xml
Information:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Information:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Information:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Schwerwiegend:   Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/E:/Work/Projects/Java/XWars/XWars-ear/target/gfdeploy/XWars-ear/
! ! ! Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 20ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Information:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (10.819ms), startup services(1.002ms), total(11.821ms)
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Information:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@32b9bd12 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@576c5536.
Information:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://Tobias-PC.fritz.box:8686/jndi/rmi://Tobias-PC.fritz.box:8686/jmxrmi
Information:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
! ! ! Warnung:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Information:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 15ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warnung:   Originally deployed application at E:\Work\Projects\Java\XWars\XWars-ear\target\gfdeploy\XWars-ear not found
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   Java security manager is disabled.
Information:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Information:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Information:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Information:   de.dnhax.xwars.persistence.entities.Player actually got transformed
Information:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5
Information:   /file:/E:/Work/Projects/Java/XWars/XWars-ear/target/gfdeploy/XWars-ear/XWars-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT_jar/_XWarsPU login successful
! ! ! Information:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Information:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Information:   Created virtual server server
Information:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Information:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Information:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Information:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [3700]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB XWarsLogicImpl: [java:global/XWars-ear/XWars-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/XWarsLogicImpl!de.dnhax.xwars.logic.XWarsLogic, java:global/XWars-ear/XWars-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/XWarsLogicImpl]
Information:   Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB XWarsLogicImpl: [de.dnhax.xwars.logic.XWarsLogic#de.dnhax.xwars.logic.XWarsLogic, de.dnhax.xwars.logic.XWarsLogic]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB PlayerAccess: [java:global/XWars-ear/XWars-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/PlayerAccess, java:global/XWars-ear/XWars-ejb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/PlayerAccess!de.dnhax.xwars.persistence.PlayerAccess]
Information:   WELD-000900: 2.2.13 (Final)
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Information:   Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) für Kontext '/xwars' wird initialisiert.
Information:   RewritePhaseListener starting up.
Information:   Monitoring jndi:/server/xwars/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Information:   Running on PrimeFaces 6.0
Information:   RewriteFilter starting up...
Information:   Loaded [4] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.RewriteLifecycleListener [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.prettyfaces.PrettyFacesRewriteLifecycleListener<-100>, org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.FacesRewriteLifecycleListener<0>, org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.DefaultRewriteLifecycleListener<2147483647>, org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.lifecycle.JoinRewriteLifecycleListener<2147483647>]
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.RequestCycleWrapper [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteRequestCycleWrapper<0>]
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.RewriteProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.DefaultHttpRewriteProvider<0>]
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.RewriteResultHandler [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler<0>]
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.InboundRewriteProducer [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpInboundRewriteProducer<0>]
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.OutboundRewriteProducer [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpOutboundRewriteProducer<0>]
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.ContextListener [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.prettyfaces.PrettyConfigContextListener<0>]
Information:   Loaded [0] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.RequestListener []
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.RequestParameterProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.prettyfaces.PrettyFacesRequestParameterProvider<0>]
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.el.spi.ExpressionLanguageProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.FacesExpressionLanguageProvider<30>]
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.InvocationResultHandler [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.NavigatingInvocationResultHandler<100>]
Information:   Loaded [0] org.ocpsoft.common.spi.ServiceEnricher []
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.ConfigurationCacheProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.ServletContextConfigurationCacheProvider<0>]
Information:   Loaded [2] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.ConfigurationProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.annotation.config.AnnotationConfigProvider<100>, org.ocpsoft.rewrite.prettyfaces.PrettyFacesRewriteConfigurationProvider<1>]
Information:   Loaded [0] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.RuleCacheProvider []
Information:   Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.GlobalParameterProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.instance.WildcardParameterProvider<0>]
Information:   Rewrite 3.4.1.Final initialized.
Information:   Loading application [XWars-ear#XWars-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war] at [/xwars]
Information:   XWars-ear was successfully deployed in 10.439 milliseconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have following entry in your web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Enforce HTTPS for all urls</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbxw.html

Comment: I have. After further investigation this seems to be a NetBeans issue (as described [here](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1108)). Bug is reported [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=268195).